# Compare the tablespace concept between Postgres and Oracle

Tags: postgresql-9.4

When I create a table, it is placed in a default tablespace such as "USERS", unless I specify a user created tablespace, say, MyTableSpace.

For example,

```
create table test_tab(

name varchar2(100),
photo BLOB,
text   CLOB
)
tablespace "USERS"   --default
lob ("photo")  tablespace "MyTableSpace"   --user created
lob ("text")  tablespace "MyTableSpace"    --user created
```

Now, convert the above table to the counterpart in Postgres.  Where could those columns be placed?

A default tablespace?  User create tablespace?  Or some proprietary logical structure in Postgres?

Comment: long `bytea` (the equivalent to `BLOB`)  and text values are stored in the [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html) area. I believe that is always the same tablespace as the table is using.

Answer (score 2):

In PostgreSQL, if you don't specify a tablespace in your CREATE TABLE command, the value of parameter default_tablespace will be used.

If default_tablespace is not set, or has an invalid value, the table will be created in the same tablespace as the database.

https://demo.pganalyze.com/databases/6/config/default_tablespace